# Soft Delete implementation fails for table with Foreign keys as composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, soft-delete

In Sql Server I have a table with following structure.

**(CustomerKey|ProductKey|Quantity|CreatedOn|ModifiedOn|DeletedOn)**
(GUID,GUID,int,TimeStamp,TimeStamp,TimeStamp)

Primary Key (CustomerKey, ProductKey)
Index

1. (CustomerKey, ProductKey)
2. (Customerkey, ProductKey, DeletedOn)

index 2 is being used to implement soft delete so that when a record is deleted, the DeletedOn is set. so in a table we may have different records with different delete dates but only one record with delete date as null.

this strategy works for tables with single key as primary. the table in question has a composite key with both keys are actually foreign keys.

now consider a record 
(xxx-xx-xx, yyy-yy-yy, 12, '2009-12-1', null, null)

I delete this record. now reinsert for the same customer and same primary key. but since the keys are being duplicated i.e. customer and product key therefore it cannot be added.

Any solutions?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also a better explanation of what you want to accomplish with the soft deletes would add context.  Why can't you add something back in after it has been deleted, for instance?

Comment: Create a history table. Why do you want duplicate records for the same customer / product? Update the `CreatedOn` column when you want to reinsert that customer / product combination.

Comment: Timestamp, despite its name, is not a date/time column. So you wont be able to put date in there. Assume you mean DATETIME. In any case this sort of table with a single modified date doesn't give you a lot as you have no idea what the update was and what else might have happened before the update. As others have suggested a History table is a much better idea. You then only need 1 date in the history (as first row is the created date), and a deleted flag in the main table.

Comment: this is the general structure for all the tables. works well for the table where guid is generated at runtime. so even though we have same data the id is different. but where we cannot change the ids like its actually representing a row in another table there we have this issue

Comment: @SimpleFellow did you find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Have a surrogate key instead of compoaite key and define unique index that includes both foreign keys + deleted on. Deleted on should be nullable. So for all combinations of foreign keys there can be only on OnDeleted as null. If you do not want to reference it further then you can have primary key with OnDeleted or isDeleted as part of Composite key but it would be an ugly solution.